# Conditional generic works differently when passed generic function parameter than when directly passed type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a utility function which will take either a tuple or an array and return whichever it took. I've constructed a generic type which understands whether it is passed a tuple or an array, but when I try to use the generic in my utility function, the generic doesn't detect the tuple:

```js
type Foo = [number, number]

type MaybeFoo<T> = T extends Foo ? Foo : number[]

const bar = [1, 1, 1, 2]
const baz: Foo = [1, 1]

type WasntFoo = MaybeFoo<typeof bar> // WasntFoo is number[], which is what I want
type WasFoo = MaybeFoo<typeof baz> // WasFoo is [number, number], which is what I want

const utilityFunction = <T,>(arr: MaybeFoo<T>): MaybeFoo<T> => arr // in real life this does something to each el of arr but doesn't change the type

const r1 = utilityFunction(bar)
const r2 = utilityFunction(baz) // r2 is number[], when I want [number, number]
```

This is in TypeScript 4.8.4, playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=76&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBtAdgVwLYCMIBOANFFnoQLoBQVokUAsgIYj7xwA8AKgHzJRcoEAB7AI6ACYBnWAigB%20WYgBcpHPgKpqVAMZx0U4FFxMC-VAEYSVqDYBM1PQaMmAXqvbmbF7XWgB3Jil0YE8UZlYIdg4-OAAzY1MeWnBoAHUgsMYWNgQY1PjE1z4AehKoQKlPAEsZDHVCEjINChJ-AAtqnXaoWor2piMASQqmEJonQyg4hBhMdB1gav1%20biIeAApTAlUI3M5eAEpdnKi83mQ%20bYn9KYILfhm4OYWl-Q2TAkPdW6MCO0es3mi2W6A%20TFchygZSg-16MmahC0bXa4igI0CITQiOIanIBAoQA)

Comment: Do you specifically need the `MaybeFoo` type, or do you just want to be able to get the end result you describe?

Comment: I just want to be able to get the end result

Comment: *Technically*, you can do that [like this](https://tsplay.dev/weQ81w), but I have a strong suspicion that's not what you're trying to do. :-) Can you edit that to show me where it would fail in your actual use case?

Comment: Thanks, edited. The issue is that the utility function is passed an array of objects, and needs to know about their contents. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: No worries, I was pretty sure that was too simplistic. :-) You've said "edited" but I don't see a new link. (You can use https://tsplay.dev to shorten playground links in order to post them to comments.)

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WGAdKN :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account [your second example](https://tsplay.dev/WGAdKN) where `Foo` is a different array type, I can only make it work without specifying the type argument explicitly by using a type assertion that ***seems*** safe to me (but I've been wrong many times about that, which is why I hate type assertions). First, a quick adjustment to `MaybeFoo`'s false branch to just result in the input type:

```typescript
type MaybeFoo<T extends Foo | any[]> = T extends Foo ? Foo : T;
```

Then the function applies a constraint on `T`, either `T extends Foo | number[]` (in your original example) or `T extends Foo | Movie[]` (in your second example); here's the `number[]` version:

```typescript
const fooFunction = <T extends Foo | number[],>(arr: T): MaybeFoo<T> => arr as MaybeFoo<T>;
```

Your test cases (plus a few):

```typescript
const r1 = fooFunction(bar);
//    ^? const r1: number[]
const r2 = fooFunction(baz); // r2 is number[], when I want [number, number]
//    ^? const r2: Foo
const r3 = fooFunction([42]);
//    ^? const r3: [number]
const r4 = fooFunction([]);
//    ^? const r4: []
const rX = fooFunction(["x"]); // Error as desired, doesn't fit the constraint
//    ^? (irrelevant, it's an error)
const rY = fooFunction("x"); // Error as desired, doesn't fit the constraint
//    ^? (irrelevant, it's an error)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBtAdgVwLYCMIBOANFFnoQLoDcAUDaJFALICGI+8cAPACpQQAPYBHQATAM6wEUAD5QW6EKgoA+ZFD6DhYyZygB+KYgBcG2jQDGcdOOBRcLAutQBGEm6geATNUvXb9iwAXqZ6KK7uvvTg0ADqLOLowGHMbBwIXAwQcABmgQQqtAD0RVBlUAB6+tGM8eIprOwQnJkxuYFBhVAlUHV6AJaSGDj4xKQjlCQA7gAW-RYzUINQsyx2AJIrCsA0PeVVdFY2djkIMJjoFsD91uq8-EIiEkay4+QEykQqABSOBKY8ACUpka6W4PDUSDUf3kklBzQyEPMRwCBBc6lOcHOl2u1m+DgIgOKpX21RRdgIXgxZwuVxu6HxwSJ3VKlKWkjIo0+KxmIigmym2zQnMIJBFBAouxJZQO5KgBAAzNSsbTcQzUAAWHxEqXlSpk-wUjXK7F0vHKHV7GUG47ygAaJtV9O+qAARAJXRRmT0AKIEAhwJwJKCiCDifoECCiEiiOBh9AAchO-TswF5UHJBBY-SSutJfltBAAmo6cc73a7vaU-QGg5JQ+HI9GQ3HEkmoDkU1A09BM9nc1b9TQgA) ([`Movie` version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwUG8BQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNz4C++YAngA4oBi6dMgC8yANoZsEADRosOALqtOvFKjhcARhEHoAPABVkEAB6QQAExrI9yAD7I4ILuMUA+UcmNmL120LIAPwBwtSGKgjoIHTIWnBQXuK4JORUyABEACI4yAASCZYZbHIppBTUGQBCDJaMEGDIAFLREDTFpeXpGQAyAPKGAErFyvhRMY3xAF7UdmLJqRWZOSgFUEUlyGVplTXAdQ3Nre0lo6p8yADqcDTgc2iaOnr63HzoMHEJ7qwA9D-EyAAekFzihrjR7hptLohC81O9PlNvsg-lcbnZgDZJApZPJpIo5AB3AAWwAQxOQmOQJLgjQAktTnGB8KjiMD8GNorEYEJ+ABXEAIMDAaJeIwmcwQKw2OyOKQ4NwydwACgSUHCAEpqFCnrDDJ4RJ41U4bDqYQZ9ZEuY0oABGLw89D8wXC6LK+JQDW-f5skHjWJQABMDt5AqFIpA7rgUy9KP+QcpNhAfLIOigiupxKlyAZhKZEmTqegckLacULJ9RHZ-ptAGYQ06w67IwsupUAMroChgUkgRhXYAAGw2yEUXorAOr1uQUAALA3neG3W5x6yq37p1AABoLpsR5XiDKmDJj5hx5AAUSgUHQiRuyEsbWAUAgljklnQbRAAHJGjBgI0PYoDWUBwKAzJrkCG4TDOACau4uvuR4ZLGqJXjed42I+NDPq+76frcv7IP+gFZsgIFgeAE6+vgQA))

Or if you want the "other" type to be **any** array type, use `any[]` instead of `number[]` or `Movie[]`:

```typescript
const fooFunction = <T extends Foo | any[],>(arr: T): MaybeFoo<T> => arr as MaybeFoo<T>;
```

Then this test case changes from a desired error to success with type `[string]`.

```typescript
const rX = fooFunction(["x"]); // <== Now this one is allowed
//    ^? const rX: [string]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwUG8BQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNz4C++YAngA4oBi6dMgC8yANoZsEADRosOALqtOvFKjhcARhEHoAPABVkEAB6QQAExrI9yAD7I4ILuMUA+UcmNmL120LIAPwBwtSGKgjoIHTIWnBQXuK4JORUyABEACI4yAASCZYZbHIppBTUGQBCDJaMEGDIAFLREDTFpeXpGQAyAPKGAErFyvhRMY3xAF7UdmLJqRWZOSgFUEUlyGVplTXAdQ3Nre0lo6p8yADqcDTgc2iaOnr63HzoMHEJ7qwA9D-EyAAekFzihrjR7hptLohC81O9PlNvsg-lcbnZgDZJApZPJpIo5AB3AAWwAQxOQmOQJLgjQAktTnGB8KjiMD8GNorEYEJ+ABXEAIMDAaJeIwmcwQKw2OyOZyuAnuAAUCSg4QAlNQoU9YYZPCJPKqnDZtTCDHrIlzGlAAIxeHnofmC4XRJXxKDq37-Nkg8axKAAJntvIFQpFIDdcCmnpR-0DlJsID5ZB0UDcROJUuQDMJTIkSZT0DkBdTihZ3qI7L91oAzMHHaGXRGFl1KgBldAUMCkkCMK7AAA2G2Qik95YBVatyCgABZ606w663GPWZXfVOoAANeeN8NK8QZUwZUfMWPIfQiMQAOXQhOQ3aprQTTgHA9vEEs459nIm04Amjuzp7oeGQxqiACiUBQOgiQ3MglhtMAUAfnIljoG0IAAOSNDAwCNN2KDVlAcCgMyq5AiCQA)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the TypeScript compiler can not correctly infer `T` in your function call. In this case the compiler defaults to `unknown` and as `unknown` does not extend `Foo` the type will be evaluated as `number[]`. If you add a typing to your function call it works as expected:

```js
const r2 = utilityFunction<Foo>(baz)
```